# How to differentiate between 2 drop downs having similar ID (with changing only last 3 digits) on the same page?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In my application in one of the create screen i have 2 drop downs having similar ID as below:

1st drop down ID: j_idt129_label

&

2nd drop down ID: j_idt147_label

Now i want to select a value from the first dropdown.

One way is By considering the XPATH without considering the dropdown's ID.

Is there any other way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work for you. This will select the first dropdown:

```
(//select[contains(@id, 'j_itd')])[1]
```

To find the second one:

```
(//select[contains(@id, 'j_itd')])[2]
```

`select` is the tag I'm guessing is in your HTML, but you may need to update `select` to match the actual tag.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for your reply. But the drop down in my application is select drop down. But i tried with

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'j_itd')][2]")).click();

The above command also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are the drop down ID's (three digits) are keep on changing? If not, then you can directly use them, else, consider corresponding parent element and get its child (drop down) elements.

Comment: Yeah, using the XPATH by considering some parent element is working fine. But is there any other way?